# Drawing parallel connections on SVG

Tags: svg

I need to generate multiple parallel connections from an original one, as shown in code:
[image: Showcase]

Code:

```
<svg width="800" height="800">

  <!-- one filter -->

  <g transform="translate(50,50)">
    <text y="50">Original</text>
   <path d="m  0,0L0,100 L100,100 " style="fill: none; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: blueviolet; stroke-linejoin: round; marker-end: url(&quot;#sequenceflow-end-white-black-0ctpawyb4xrqoyjc7rrbh92fl&quot;);"></path>

  </g>

  <g transform="translate(250,50)">
    <text y="50">Generated</text>
    <path d="m  0,0L0,100 L100,100 " style="fill: none; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: blueviolet; stroke-linejoin: round; marker-end: url(&quot;#sequenceflow-end-white-black-0ctpawyb4xrqoyjc7rrbh92fl&quot;);"></path>
    <path d="m  10,0L10,90 L100,90 " style="fill: none; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: blueviolet; stroke-linejoin: round; marker-end: url(&quot;#sequenceflow-end-white-black-0ctpawyb4xrqoyjc7rrbh92fl&quot;);"></path>
    <path d="m  20,0L20,80 L100,80 " style="fill: none; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: blueviolet; stroke-linejoin: round; marker-end: url(&quot;#sequenceflow-end-white-black-0ctpawyb4xrqoyjc7rrbh92fl&quot;);"></path>
  </g>


  <g transform="translate(50,250)">
    <text y="50">Original</text>

    <path d="m  0,0L10,90 L100,70 " style="fill: none; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: blueviolet; stroke-linejoin: round; marker-end: url(&quot;#sequenceflow-end-white-black-0ctpawyb4xrqoyjc7rrbh92fl&quot;);"></path>

  </g>

  <g transform="translate(250,250)">
    <text y="50">Generated</text>
     <path d="m  0,0L10,90 L100,70 " style="fill: none; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: blueviolet; stroke-linejoin: round; marker-end: url(&quot;#sequenceflow-end-white-black-0ctpawyb4xrqoyjc7rrbh92fl&quot;);"></path>
     <path d="m  10,0L20,80 L100,60 " style="fill: none; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: blueviolet; stroke-linejoin: round; marker-end: url(&quot;#sequenceflow-end-white-black-0ctpawyb4xrqoyjc7rrbh92fl&quot;);"></path>
  </g>

</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyObNr

Is there any easy way to do it? Something like cloning and just making it fit along the original one would be perf

regards

Answer (score 3):

Svg provides the means for reuse of partial drawings with the `defs` element. It may contain groups (`g` element) that contain an arbitrarily complex scene. These may be referenced thereafter with the `use` element which effectively produces a clone which can then be subjected to transformations (an arbitrary mix of rotations, scalings, translations).

What follows is a reformulation of your sample scene:

```svg
<svg
    width="800" height="800"
    version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
    <defs>
        <g id="angle">
            <path d="m  0,0L0,100 L100,100 " style="fill: none; stroke-width: 2px; stroke: blueviolet; stroke-linejoin: round; marker-end: url(&quot;#sequenceflow-end-white-black-0ctpawyb4xrqoyjc7rrbh92fl&quot;);"></path>
        </g>
        <g id="multi">
            <use xlink:href="#angle" />
            <use xlink:href="#angle" transform="translate(10,-10)"/>
            <use xlink:href="#angle" transform="translate(20,-20)"/>
        </g>
    </defs>

    <!-- base case -->
    <g transform="translate(50,50)">
        <text x="50" y="50">Original</text>
        <use xlink:href="#angle"/>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(50,50) translate(200,0)">
        <text x="50" y="50">Generated</text>
        <use xlink:href="#multi" />
    </g>

    <!-- rotated -->
    <g transform="translate(50,50) translate(0,200)">
        <text x="50" y="50">Original</text>
        <g transform="rotate(-20)">
            <use xlink:href="#angle"/>
        </g>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(50,50) translate(200,200)">
        <text x="75" y="25">Generated</text>
        <g transform="rotate(-20)">
            <use xlink:href="#multi"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```